# How to compute categorical probability given a continuous distribution?

Tags: regression, probability, gamma-distribution

I have a continuous target column that consists of IQ scores for kids of age 10. My main purpose is to forecast the probability that a kid is genius given 3 covariates. If a kid has IQ over 160 she/he will be labelled 1(genius) if not 0.I am told rather than using logistic regression and converting my continuous target column to a categorical one, I can also use a continuous distribution to fit the data  and then compute probability from the distribution.

So I fit a Glm Gamma model to the data and now I have a model that I can get forecasts on IQ score given a test data. From this point on how can I compute the probability that a kid is genius? I have the parameters from the summary of the model. I thought I could use R's dgamma(). But how will I set threshold as 160 and given my test data how will I compute probabilities from independent variables?

Comment: I think it might be a little misleading to provide a probability that the kid is a genius based on the IQ prediction as it goes against the frequentist definition of probability you are working with (you would want to work in a Bayesian setting for this).  What you can do is use the `predict` function to derive a confidence/prediction interval around your IQ estimate.

Comment: @ForrestKoch How does it go against frequentist probability?

Comment: @Dave correct me if I'm wrong, but my understanding is that in a frequentist setting you regard the parameter of interest as fixed.  In this setting, you construct α-level intervals which when used, will contain the true parameter 100*α% of the time, but you can't make probability statements about the parameter of interest.  In a Bayesian setting, the parameter of interest is allowed to be a random variable, therefore can have probabilities associated with it.

Comment: @Forrest can the probability be determined if we do not consider the prediction given but the test set given and we know the distribution parameters?

Comment: Your model outputs a conditional distribution over iq, right? So you can use this to compute the probability that iq > 160. Evaluate the CDF at 160 (which gives the probability that iq $\le$ 160), then subtract this value from 1.

Comment: @moli I think it's largely an issue of semantics, and perhaps I'm over-complicating things by nitpicking the wording.  Ultimately what I think you are after is equivalent to deriving a prediction interval, however, instead of reporting the bounds for a given α, you want to find the α resulting in the PI including 160.  I also think it is important that I amend my previous statement about using the `predict` function.  It turns out that prediction intervals are quite difficult to generate for the GLM and this can't be done using `predict`.

Comment: for a discussion about gamma GLM PI's see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/423169/gamma-glm-derive-prediction-intervals-for-new-x-i  which refers to this relevent paper https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00949655.2016.1169421?scroll=top&needAccess=true