# Is this the correct way to compute confidence intervals on the original scale for GLM(M)s?

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, generalized-linear-model, link-function, back-transformation

Suppose I have fitted a GLM and want to produce a confidence interval (or a prediction interval) on the original scale of the outcome. What I would do is estimate it on the link scale and then inverse transform the interval.

For example, if I have the output of a Poisson GLM:

```
> confint(GLM)

                 2.5 %      97.5 %
(Intercept)  0.7616609  1.90330787
x            0.4118273  1.74089636
```

Then the intercept would give me:

$$\text{CI}_{95\%} = e^{[0.7616609, \, 1.90330787]} = [2.1, \, 6.7]$$

My question is, is this the right way? Is there a better way to obtain confidence intervals on the original scale? What about prediction intervals?

Comment: Better in what way?  Also, I have detailed how one could approximate prediction intervals [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/498795/how-to-calculate-prediction-interval-in-glm-gamma-tweedieregression-in-pytho/498800#498800) by leveraging a normal approximation to the model likelihood

Comment: That is great, I will definitely have a look at your post

Comment: I just wondered if there were a more efficient method, perhaps providing narrower intervals?